Is Cockney still spoken?
Wiki says:
"Cockney is a dialect of the English language, mainly spoken in London and its environs, particularly by Londoners with working-class and lower middle-class roots. The term Cockney is also used as a demonym for a person from the East End,[1][2][3] or, traditionally, born within earshot of Bow Bells.[4][5][6]"
Have present-day Cockney speakers retained the way Cockney was represented in say, Dickens or Bernard Shaw?  What is its geography now?

I don’t think any dialect of any language on earth can be said to be spoken now the way it was 150 years ago.

How much of the Cockney 'diaspora' would you include in your definition of "Cockney speakers"?

That is interesting.  But I am more interested in whether cockney-speakers are "bilingual" and whether their cockney is under pressure from more standard dialects.
@Michaelyus.  Fr example, it looks like nobody says "toity-toid street" in Brooklyn anymore.

Downvoters, can you explain yourselves?

I don't have scholarly sources, but anecdotally, whilst cockney is still spoken (and as with most regional dialects, speakers show a degree of diglossia and are able to assimilate somewhat to national and regional norms, and ofc the Cockney of today is not the same as the Cockney of Dickens or Shaw's day), it's declined significantly as Estruary English has rapidly expanded, and also as Multicultural London English has developed

Someone is deleting my comments. I said why wouldn't one trust that first sentence on Wikepedia? The 150 years is a separate question. By bilingual, I guess what you mean is code switching, like American Blacks who can switch from AAVE to standard English. Or white people who can move from speaking unschooled English to standard English. Think of the actor Michael Caine: In interviews, he mostly uses standard English, but his accent is Cockney. Listen to him: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBjp1oEZcwU

He keeps the accent but not the various structures of Cockney. And he says so himself. Changing an accent, though, it not code switching. That involves grammar and sentence structure. And toity-toid street was originally from Yiddish speakers.

@Lambie You don't have any deleted comments on this question!

@curiousdannii I posted a sentence to the effect of: Don't you trust what the Wikipedia article says? I saw it posted and when I returned it was gone. You don't need to use an exclamation mark like that. I am saying this as I remember it.

There are no deleted comments on this question, from anyone. Maybe you wrote it on another question, but it wasn't this one.
